# (Swift) Fade-In and Out a Label

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to fade a label in and out when it appears on the screen. Currently, I'm simply hiding it using

```
button.hidden = true
```

and unhiding it by using false. I would like to animate this process with a fade-in and out as it looks much smoother this way. Appreciate the help !

Here is the code I'm using which gets an error.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAktk.jpg

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var yeah: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.yeah.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {
            (finished: Bool) -> Void in

            //Once the label is completely invisible, set the text and fade it back in
            self.yeah.text = "your Text "

            // Fade in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.yeah.alpha = 1.0
                }, completion: {
                    (finished: Bool) -> Void in

                    //Once the label is completely invisible, set the text and fade it back in
                    self.yeah.text = "your Text "

                    // Fade in
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                        self.yeah.alpha = 1.0
                        }, completion:nil )




            })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}
}

Comment: Are you looking for a hide with fade out, and show with fade in effect?  As default hide is not animatable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [andrew bancroft's blog](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/07/27/fade-in-out-animations-as-class-extensions-with-swift/)

```
     // Move our fade out code from earlier
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.yourLabel.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {
            finished in

            if finished {
                //Once the label is completely invisible, set the text and fade it back in
                self.yourLabel.text = "your Text "

                // Fade in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                    self.yourLabel.alpha = 1.0
                }, completion: nil)
            }
    })
```

**Modified Answer**

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.yourLabel.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {
            finished in

            if finished {
                //Once the label is completely invisible, set the text and fade it back in
              self.yourLabel.text = "your Text "

                // Fade in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                  self.yourLabel.alpha = 1.0
                    }, completion: {
                        finished in

                        if finished {
                            //Once the label is completely invisible, set the text and fade it back in
                              self.yourLabel.text = "your Text "

                            // Fade in
                            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                                self.yourLabel.alpha = 0.0
                                }, completion: nil)
                        }
                })
            }
    })
```

Comment: You should add `if finished {}` to your closure. The completion block _might_ be called when it's unfinished.

Comment: If you refer someone's code its good to write name as reference first.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara - sure my bro, can you modify answer I followed your way

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thank you.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara - tanx buddy I follow onwards have a nice day my fried

Comment: Thanks, that faded the text in, but how shall I go about fading it back out? Sorry, still a little new to swift.

Comment: @Ash - if you want o go back again you need to call again one animation in here `completion: nil)`

Comment: I did that, but I'm getting this error...don't know if I implemented it correctly.http://imgur.com/a/HI4eg @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Ash - can you updated the code in your question

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik done

Comment: @Ash - check teh modified answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks for all the help, that did it